# Verify Error Java at Run time

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am getting the following error when running my program. Compilation works just fine! and the program was working a min ago wht the hell is going on?! can you please help

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: FinalTest, method: <init> signature: ()V) Constructor must call super() or this()
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:484)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:476)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560988/method-must-call-super-error-in-netbeans

Comment: Difficult to say anything about this before you post any code.

Comment: Working a minute ago?  What changed?  There's your first clue.

Comment: At least, you should show us the constructor of FinalTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javadoc says:

> Thrown when the "verifier" detects that a class file, though well
>   formed, contains some sort of internal inconsistency or security
>   problem.

As you application was running a mintute ago, it should not be a security issue. Cleanup all your `.class` files, rebuild your application and run it. Also, check your compilation warnings to make sure you don't have conflicting dependencies.

Comment: Had this error, drove me nuts! Looking at the warnings definitely helped!

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the whole project .. and run the new one.. It worked for me.