# java.lang.VerifyError: (class: ea/Individual, method: <init> signature: (I)V) Constructor must call super() or this()

Tags: java, netbeans

I am not finding any error in this class, but Netbeans continuously showing red symbol on that class. Class is

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ea;

/**
 *
 * @author riyad
 */

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.BitSet;

public class Individual 
{
    BitSet variable;

    double x;
    double fitness;
    double sharedFitness;
    final int SIZE;


    Random generator = new Random();

    public Individual(int SIZE)
    {
        this.variable = new BitSet(SIZE);
        this.fitness = 0;
        this.sharedFitness = 0;
        this.SIZE = SIZE;


        for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        {
            if(generator.nextBoolean())
            {
                variable.set(i);
            }
            else
            {
                variable.clear(i);
            }
        }

        x = Double.parseDouble(variable.toString());
    }


    public Individual copy()
    {
        Individual ind = new Individual(SIZE);

        this.variable = (BitSet) ind.variable.clone();
        this.fitness = ind.fitness;
        this.sharedFitness = ind.sharedFitness;
        this.x = ind.x;

        return ind;
    }

    public void evaluate()
    {
        fitness = x * Math.sin(Math.sqrt(x));
    }

    public boolean getBit(int i)
    {
        return variable.get(i);
    }

    public BitSet getBitSet()
    {
        return variable;
    }

    public void setBit(int i)
    {
        variable.set(i);
    }

    public void clearBit(int i)
    {
        variable.clear(i);
    }

    public double getFitness()
    {
        return fitness;
    }

    public double sharedFitness()
    {
        return sharedFitness;
    }

    public void setSharedFitness(double fitness)
    {
        this.sharedFitness = fitness;
    }

    public void setFitness(double fitness)
    {
        this.fitness = fitness;
    }
}
```

The code is compiling but getting runtime error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: ea/Individual, method: <init> signature: (I)V) Constructor must call super() or this()
```

In another class, where Individual class is being used:

```
ArrayList<Individual> pop = new ArrayList<Individual>();
```

This where Individual class is being intantiated:

```
Individual temp = new Individual(STRING_SIZE);
pop.add(temp);
```

**EDIT**

I haven't renamed the file manually. All the coding was done in Netbeans. The only problem is when I am creating instance of Individual.

**EDIT2**

I have copied the project another place, everything is normal again. probably a bug of Netbeans or JDK

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: The current code seems correct, the problem might be in the usage of the class Individual. How do you create an instance of it?

Comment: @stacker: didn't understand a bit. I am e newbie

Comment: I don't see any error in Eclipse when I create a project with this class.

Comment: Yeah, could you add the code that you use to create the instance? Something like `Individual indv1 = new Individual(5);`?

Comment: You need to explain what have you done from the beginning.

Comment: This seems to be a Netbeans specific quirk when having duplicate classes of the same signature in different packages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560988/method-must-call-super-error-in-netbeans Probably you renamed old classes manually by file explorer instead of using IDE refactoring functions. Cleansweep your project.

Comment: My easiest solution is to back up, delete the offending java file and copy it back. See [Uncompilable Source Code after duplicate Copy](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230497)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `javap` the .class file and check whether the compiler generated a call to super() near the start of your constructor.

The JVM verifier requires that any constructor (other than for Object, of course) invoke (possibly indirectly via another constructor) it's superclass's constructor.  Normally the compiler inserts a call to the superclass constructor automatically if you don't do it, but it's possible that it could be confused into not doing this under some circumstances (though the code presented doesn't seem that complex).

(And, yes, you have `this` and `ind` swapped in most places in `copy`.)

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not the problem, but your `copy()` method is totally messed up... Instead of copying anything, it actually just resets the original object, and returns a new empty one. If you wanted it to create copies of the object, you should do something like this:

```
public Individual copy()
{
    Individual ind = new Individual(SIZE);

    ind.variable = (BitSet) this.variable.clone();
    ind.fitness = this.fitness;
    ind.sharedFitness = this.sharedFitness;
    ind.x = this.x;

    return ind;
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
Individual newOne = oldOne.copy();
```

Comment: Glad to help, but if this fixed your problem, it is by chance :P Check Hot Licks answer for a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Netbeans. Clean and then Build the project again solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have the same experience with NetBeans. I was pretty mad about it, but the solution is quite easy.
You have to copy create new projects and the same classes as in the not-functional one. Then copy all the texts from the classes in old project to new project and don't forget to change package name if it isn't the same. Your work will then run :)

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.VerifyError can be the result when you have compiled against a different library than you are using at runtime.

For example, this happened to me when trying to run a program that was compiled against Xerces 1, but Xerces 2 was found on the classpath. The required classes (in org.apache.* namespace) were found at runtime, so ClassNotFoundException was not the result. There had been changes to the classes and methods, so that the method signatures found at runtime did not match what was there at compile-time.

Normally, the compiler will flag problems where method signatures do not match. The JVM will verify the bytecode again when the class is loaded, and throws VerifyError when the bytecode is trying to do something that should not be allowed -- e.g. calling a method that returns String and then stores that return value in a field that holds a List. This is what I got, But still I am unable to correct it..