# Java: No main classes found - following books example

Tags: java

I am currently in a Java class using *[Java: How to Program, Ninth Edition](http://www.isbnsearch.org/isbn/0132575663)*

I am following the book in creating a GradeBook and have come across an error stating no main classes found.

Here is the code for the two files in my project folder:

GradeBook.java

```
// Fig. 2.1: GradeBook.java
// Class declaration with one method.
public class GradeBook
{
    // display a welcome message to the GradeBook user
    public void displayMessage()
    {
        System.out.println ( "Welcome to the Grade Book!");
    } // end method displayMessage
} // end class GradeBook
```

GradeBookTest.java

```
// Fig. 3.2: GradeBookTest.java
// Creating a GradeBook object and calling its displayMessage method.

public class GradeBookTest
{
    // main method begins program execution
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // create a GradeBook object and assign it to myGradeBook
        GradeBook myGradeBook = new GradeBook();

        // call myGradeBook's displayMessage method
        myGradeBook.displayMessage();
    } // end main
} // end class GradeBookTest
```

I am using the NetBeans IDE to create and run my projects. It is only my second week into my Java class so I am still learning and working my way around NetBeans and Java.  Any advice would be awesome.

Comment: have not used netbeans in a long time but i remembered in the project setting you can select which .java file is the main class. i suspect that you may be running `GradeBook.java` instead of `GradeBookTest.java`

Comment: which class are you trying to run ? GradeBook or GradeBookTest ?

Comment: right click on the GradeBookTest.java and run as Java Program if you are running NetBeans IDE

Comment: I tried just right clicking on GradeBookTest.java and running the file and get the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was eclipse, I would have just run the main method in the GradeBookTest. Are you trying to run the project ? or just the GradeBookTest main ?
Try running GradeBookTest.

Comment: I tried right clicking on GradeBookTest and get the following, Error: Could not find or load main class GradeBookTest
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: In project properties, select Run and the MainClass as GradeBookTest You should read this small tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/netbeans.html#netbeans-2d)

Comment: @Usdblades What that means is you are running the wrong file. If you right click on GradeBookTest, and find the run button, that should work. Alternatively, there is a function key that runs the file you are on, not sure which one it is, which is why I won't answer it, but try that.

Comment: @Andy I tried right clicking on GradeBookTest.java and clicking run file and get the same error

Comment: Are you sure both files are in the same project? BY default from what I remember, Netbeans makes them inside packages. Maybe your packages are all wrong.

Comment: @codezilla I will take a look at the tutorial but when I go to project properties, I select Run and when I go to MainClass and click Browse I get the no Main Classes error.

Comment: @Usdblades Did you put the classes in proper packages ?

Comment: @Andy Both of my .java files are in the Default Packages

Comment: @Usdblades that might be the reason. faintly remember that to be the issue. name your packages instead of leaving them as default

Comment: Yes, I agree with @codezilla another thing might be what you named the files. Make sure the part before the .java is named the class name. Like so GradeBookTest.java and GradeBook.java respectively.

Comment: @codezilla I tried creating a new packages folder and refractoring both files into this new folder and still came up with the same issue.

Comment: Did you name the package something ? Like com.gradebook ? Yeah, the name of the class and the filename should be same. Also, even if that does not work, then check the classpath.

Comment: @Andy I triple checked that my file names were the same as the class names letter for letter paying special attention to capitalization. This was what I first suspected when I tried diagnosing it myself.

Comment: @codezilla I just named the package gradebook. I will check the classpath in a minute. Trying to check my compiler as suggested below. I have no problems running any of my other programs but they are all one file projects.

Comment: When I try and run the project, I get thisError: Could not find or load main class GradeBookTest

Comment: May be the old GradeBookTest was being referred, delete the class files and do a fresh compile

Comment: I just deleted the whole project and started from scratch Ill give you an update in about a minute or two

Comment: Now that I deleted the whole project folder and started from scratch I am not getting  run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return in method GradeBook.<init>()V at offset 0
 at GradeBookTest.main(GradeBookTest.java:10)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560988/method-must-call-super-error-in-netbeans) should help

Comment: To resolve it, I deleted the entire package from the target web app and did a clean and build. Then I copied the source package into the target application. No errors. 

What is the Target Web App? I tried right clicking on my GradeBook Project and doing a Clean and Build but still nothing

Comment: Instead, it would be easy for you to create a new project, create clean package with a name, create classes. then run only the GradeBookTest class

Comment: Ok. I deleted the GradeBook Project by right clicking on it and selection the checkmark to delete the source too. I then Created a new Project and get the same error. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Codezilla I got it working now. Not sure how but after doing the steps you mentioned for a third time, It decided to work. Thank you Codezilla and everyone who helped me. So what exactly was wrong with my project?

Comment: Might be the old classes were being referred. The first issue was leaving your package names to "default".

Comment: yeah changing the package name to something else made it work the third time :). I was just following the book and it did not mention to change the package name. Thanks a lot, I appreciate the help.

Comment: You made me think about netbeans which I used last in 2009 ! :) But, if you get some error, try googling the exact message, most of the cases, the first line of the stacktrace, you should get a ton of answers.

Comment: I must get back to homework. Thanks again and I accepted your answer codezilla.

Answer (score 0):

In the project properties, under "Run" pick `GradeBookTest` as the class to run.

Comment: I just tried this and when I go under Run and click Browse to change the main class, I get the no main classes found

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the file and pressing Ctrl+Shift+F10. If this doesn't work, check if JAVA_HOME is set properly and that you are using the correct compiler (javac) under Settings->Compiler->Java Compiler. I dont have sufficient points to post a screenshot, otherwise I have the exact thing running on my machine and I could have shared the screenshot.

Comment: alright give me a minute to try this out. I have to figure out where in Netbeans this is located.

Answer (score 0):

There are reasons and ways to solve this problem

1. the class is not located in the proper src directory of your project.
2. Secondly if you have created classes you have to compile them before they can be used as main.

Right click on the file name on the Tree menu on left and select compile. Otherwise the short cut key to compile class is F9 .

This will definitely solve your problem :) .