# Constructor must call super() or this()

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Can anyone help me with the following error report (for the code at the bottom):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return in method org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets.<init>()V at offset 0
at org.jfree.chart.axis.Axis.<clinit>(Axis.java:153)
at org.jfree.chart.StandardChartTheme.<init>(StandardChartTheme.java:233)
at org.jfree.chart.StandardChartTheme.<init>(StandardChartTheme.java:319)
at org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory.<clinit>(ChartFactory.java:231)
at odesolver.ODESolver.createGraph(ODESolver.java:81)
at odesolver.ODESolver.<init>(ODESolver.java:35)
at odesolver.ODESolver$2.run(ODESolver.java:105)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

which relates to the following 3 lines of the code:

ODESolver.java:81

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
```

ODESolver.java:35

```
createGraph();
```

ODESolver.java:105

```
new ODESolver(); // Let the constructor do the job
```

Whole program:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package odesolver;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
import java.awt.*;       // Using AWT containers and components
import java.awt.event.*; // Using AWT events and listener interfaces
import javax.swing.*;    // Using Swing components and containers
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.data.general.Series;

// A Swing GUI application inherits the top-level container javax.swing.JFrame
public class ODESolver extends JFrame {
   private JTextField tfInput, tfOutput;
   private int numberIn;   // input number
   private int sum = 0;    // accumulated sum, init to 0

   /** Constructor to setup the GUI */
   public ODESolver() {
      // Retrieve the content-pane of the top-level container JFrame
      // All operations done on the content-pane
      Container cp = getContentPane();
      cp.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 5, 5));

      createGraph();


      add(new JLabel("Enter an Integer: "));
      tfInput = new JTextField(10);
      add(tfInput);
      add(new JLabel("The Accumulated Sum is: "));
      tfOutput = new JTextField(10);
      tfOutput.setEditable(false);  // read-only
      add(tfOutput);

      // Allocate an anonymous instance of an anonymous inner class that
      //  implements ActionListener as ActionEvent listener
      tfInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Get the String entered into the input TextField, convert to int
            numberIn = Integer.parseInt(tfInput.getText());
            sum += numberIn;      // accumulate numbers entered into sum
            tfInput.setText("");  // clear input TextField
            tfOutput.setText(sum + ""); // display sum on the output TextField
         }
      });

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  // Exit program if close-window button clicked
      setTitle("ODE Accumulator"); // "this" Frame sets title
      setSize(350, 120);  // "this" Frame sets initial size
      setVisible(true);   // "this" Frame shows


   }

   private JPanel createGraph() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("MyGraph");
        series.add(0, 1);
        series.add(1, 2);
        series.add(2, 5);
        series.add(7, 8);
        series.add(9, 10);


        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(series);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                "XY Chart",
                "x-axis",
                "y-axis",
                dataset, 
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false
                );
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);


        panel.add(chartPanel);

        return panel;
    }

   /** The entry main() method */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Run the GUI construction in the Event-Dispatching thread for thread-safety
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            new ODESolver(); // Let the constructor do the job
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Maybe the problem is that there are files in ODESolver, src and lib with errors, as netbeans reports (see screenshot below). I don't know which files are upposed to have errors though, as none of then have an exclamation mark on them, as they usually do of they have errors.

[image: netbeans error]

Comment: i just tried that, but still get the same error

Comment: Adding super() to the constructor will have no effect. When no superconstructor is explicitly specified, the compiler essentially inserts the default super() as the first line of your constructor.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder AFAIK there is no need to explicitly specify that. Compiler does that for you i.e put a default super() at the start of the constructor is not explicitly specified.

Comment: most probably due to careless copies of java files (backups) since they are also compiled and collide with the original class. I found it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560988/method-must-call-super-error-in-
netbeans

Comment: @Alejadro Xalabarder Well thanks.  I actually solved this problem: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was solved by adding the jar files to the classpath, rather than the folder containing them

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be running an old version of `JFreeChart` which produces this error. Upgrade to version `1.0.13` as found [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jfree/jfreechart)

Comment: Assuming that yours works fine with v 16, I wonder what you're doing that I'm not or vice versa. By the way i was running an old version of JCommon (v8 as opposed to v 20): switching that has fixed the super() error, although there are are now some different errors.

Comment: `13` seems to be the last release, are you sure youre using version `16`?

Comment: It's in a folder called jfreechart-1.0.16, so I suppose so

Comment: I see ver `16` is not in the maven repository. Even testing with version 16 your code works. Try re-download the jar. Make sure that youre using all the related dependencies, for e.g. not using an old version of `JCommon`

Comment: Why do you mention that ver 16 is not in the maven repository? Should it be?

Comment: Because it doesnt appear in the link above - it has to be download directly, anyway a side issue

Comment: ODESolver, src and lib have red exclamation marks next to them (see screenshot I've added to the question) and reports they contain 'files with errors): I think this is the problem. However, none of the files seems to have an exclamation mark on, so I don't know which one is supposed to have errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38354/discussion-between-bluesh34-and-reimeus)

Comment: The problem will be shown if you expand the `lib` folder - can you post that as an image instead?

Answer (score -1):

The various constructors of `JFrame` do important initialisation work, that any `JFrame` requires.  Therefore, every `JFrame` that is ever created must have one of those constructors called.  But because an `ODESolver` is also a `JFrame`, that applies to `ODESolver` objects too.

Fortunately, the Java language enforces this.  We can't create an `ODESolver`, without one of the `JFrame` constructors getting called.  The way it enforces it is by requiring every `ODESolver` constructor to be mapped to a `JFrame` constructor.

When we create an `ODESolver`, one of the `ODESolver` constructors will get called.  But that constructor must specify which `JFrame` constructor will get called.  The way it does that is by doing one of the following.

- specifying explicitly which `JFrame` constructor to use, via a call to `super()`, with or without some arguments;
- calling another `ODESolver` constructor, via a call to `this()`, with or without some arguments.

In either case, the call to `super()` or `this()` must be the first line of the `ODESolver` constructor.

Comment: I tried putting super() as the first line: it didn't solve it. What did get rid of the super() error (but leave me with many other errors) was to change the version of JCommon I was using from 8 to 20.