# java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return

Tags: java, netbeans

I am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return in method freetts.FTall.()V at offset 0
>       at freetts.FormTTS.MenuContinueButtonActionPerformed(FormTTS.java:429)
>       at freetts.FormTTS.access$100(FormTTS.java:59)
>       at freetts.FormTTS$2.actionPerformed(FormTTS.java:127)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

I am checking my program after a month or so, earlier the same code didn't give errors, I suppose I have not changed anything that could be causing this.
I tried to solve the problem; so in the error in the 1st line it is mentioned:

> at freetts.FormTTS.MenuContinueButtonActionPerformed(FormTTS.java:429)

So I opened FormTTS.java:429
Here is that code:

```
private void MenuContinueButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   

        FTall allform = new FTall();
        FTdirect directform = new FTdirect();
        FTsmall1 small1form = new FTsmall1();
        FTsmall2 small2form = new FTsmall2();
        FTsmall3 small3form = new FTsmall3();
        FTbig1 big1form = new FTbig1();
        FTbig3 big3form = new FTbig3();
        FTmc1 mc1form = new FTmc1();
        FTmc2 mc2form = new FTmc2();
        String S = (String) jCB2.getSelectedItem();
        String R = (String) jCB3.getSelectedItem();
        String P = (String) jCB4.getSelectedItem();
    .....
```

Line 429 particularly is:

```
FTall allform = new FTall();
```

And this is the code of the constructor being called:

```
public FTall() {
    initComponents();
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your `FTall` constructor is broken. Please post that code.

Comment: Constructor in your FTail seem to have issues

Comment: Jon Skeet, Maciej Cygan: which FTall code?? i mean FTall is another file, (see in the image: FTall.java)

Comment: @JonSkeet This seems to be a bytecode error not representable as legal Java source code.

Comment: @DakshShah The issue is not in your code but most likely in FTall class code. So share the code for FTall

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I'd have thought so too, but we could really do with seeing the `FTall` class to say. Maybe Netbeans allows invalid Java to be compiled like Eclipse does.

Comment: @DakshShah: Don't show a *picture* of `FTall` - include the *source code* of the constructor.

Comment: Juned Ahsan Can you please be more specific?, because the code in file FTall.java is 948 lines long.. Do you want me to share the whole 948 line code?

Comment: Contents of FTall.java: http://pastebin.com/w3SAdYqy

Comment: Are you using NetBeans by any chance? Seems to be a problem with the IDE. Cleaning and building the project again solves the problem in most cases.

Comment: Codo: it works! i am using netbeans - yes and yah cleaning n building solves the problem. Does anyone know why was it caused??

Comment: most probably due to careless copies of java files (backups) since they are also compiled and collide with the original class. I found it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560988/method-must-call-super-error-in-
netbeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning and Building solves the problem